# How i drop foreign and primary key of table in migration?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

How I drop multiple foreign key and primary keys in migration file.

Bellow is my migration file code.

**Migration File**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('role_user', function(Blueprint $table){
        $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('role_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('roles')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->primary(['role_id', 'user_id']);
    });
}
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('role_user');
    //how drop foreign and primary key here ?
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Blueprint** class offers **dropForeign** and **dropPrimary** methods that allow you to remove foreign key constraints and primary key.

The following should do the trick:

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign('role_user_role_id_foreign');
        $table->dropForeign('role_user_user_id_foreign');
        $table->dropPrimary();
    });
}
```

Comment: hi @jedzej can i remove both foreign key in single dropForeign function like dropForeign(['foreign_one', 'foreign_two]);

Comment: You can't. Why would you want to do this anyway? Just to save one line in a tiny migration file?